# Text Floating Out of Sidebar

Tags: html, css

The text goes out of my div and there is no fixed width on it so i don't know why its doing this.
The sidebar should not extend any further than 200px.

HTML

```
     <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="side_box">
            <div class="side_box_title"><span>VAULT FEED</span></div>
            <div class="side_box_content">
                dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: left;
}
.side_box {

}

.side_box_title {
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.side_box_content {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with css3 word - break property. -> [Word break css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

just add to .side_box_content class the following:

```
.side_box_content {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;


    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Have a go at: -> [Test drive](http://jsfiddle.net/HDtxh/)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks alot, can't believe that i missed that, it is fully cross-browser compatible right?

Comment: according to [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/index.php) it doesnt need a vendor prefix, however, there is a good article on css-tricks, on word-break [check it out](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

Comment: or you could go with **`word-wrap: break-word;`** Both rules are similar, but **`word-break`** rule will just ignore any spaces, commas or hyphens, and break apart the word, while the **`word-wrap`** will watch for spaces, commas and hyphens, and after it'll break the word. The last one should have a max-width, or a width specified, and work best on block elements

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try

```
.side_box_content {    
    ...
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```